# Create custom sort sql, apply repeatedly to queries

Tags: mysql, sorting, bioinformatics

I have a table that records sample location in 96 well grids (locations are named A01-H12). I want to have my query export data in a specific order, by column which is the number rather than by row letter.

Example plateTable:

| PlateID | SampleID | WellPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| plate1 | Sample4 | B02 |
| plate1 | Sample10 | A01 |
| plate1 | Sample1 | B01 |
| plate1 | Sample30 | A02 |
| plate1 | Sample5 | C01 |
| plate1 | Sample8 | F01 |
| plate1 | Sample32 | B08 |
| plate1 | Sample9 | A12 |

My typical query is

Select *
From plateTable
where PlateID="plate1"

I want my output to be ordered with all the "01" first, then all the "02"..., sorted by letter within each number.

Desired output:

| PlateID | SampleID | WellPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| plate1 | Sample10 | A01 |
| plate1 | Sample1 | B01 |
| plate1 | Sample5 | C01 |
| plate1 | Sample8 | F01 |
| plate1 | Sample30 | A02 |
| plate1 | Sample4 | B02 |
| plate1 | Sample32 | B08 |
| plate1 | Sample9 | A12 |

Well position is always 1 letter, followed by 2 numbers. Is there a way to specify pulling out the last 2 digits sort that first, then sort by first letter? Or some other way to set this sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RIGHT()` function to extract the last 2 chars of `WellPosition` and sort first by these chars and then by `WellPosition`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM plateTable 
WHERE PlateID = 'plate1'
ORDER BY RIGHT(WellPosition, 2), WellPosition
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d7baef673e6a23a3d069496b5bb0bb59).
Results:

| PlateID | SampleID | WellPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| plate1 | Sample10 | A01 |
| plate1 | Sample1 | B01 |
| plate1 | Sample5 | C01 |
| plate1 | Sample8 | F01 |
| plate1 | Sample30 | A02 |
| plate1 | Sample4 | B02 |
| plate1 | Sample32 | B08 |
| plate1 | Sample9 | A12 |

Comment: YES!!! so simple. I've been trying to figure this out for so long. I'll accept as soon as stack allows